# How to reapply CSS when Sharepoint webpart refreshes

Tags: css, sharepoint, web-parts

I am using CSS to add background colors to cells in a Sharepoint ListView webpart. The trouble is, the colors disappear when the webpart refreshes - e.g. when I add an item, or when I click a column header to sort the list. Is there any way to reapply the CSS dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this one time, hope it will help you :

```
document.styleSheets.reload()
```

Comment: Greg, where would I put this line - is there an OnLoad() event for out-of-the-box webparts that I can hook into?

Comment: check this out : http://meherkanthch.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-add-onload-javascript-event-in.html